# WinDbg Unknown Method Names

Tags: c#, windbg

I am trying to work out what code is causing our application to crash using WinDbg.

We have the .pdb symbols for our compiled application in the following folder:

`E:\MyApplication`

In order to load the symbols we set the symbol path to:

`E:\MyApplication;srv*E:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;`

This should load our local pdb files from the E drive then all other symbols will be loaded from the symbol server and cached to the E:\Symbols folder.

However if I set `!sym noisy` and then run `!analyze -v`:

```
SYMSRV:  UNC: 

e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe\5AB2A76A278000\MyApplication.exe - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe\5AB2A76A278000\MyApplication.ex_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe\5AB2A76A278000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80070003
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1A
         e:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         MyApplication.exe
         5AB2A76A278000
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\symbols\MyApplication.exe\5AB2A76A278000\MyApplication.exe - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\symbols\MyApplication.exe\5AB2A76A278000\MyApplication.ex_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\symbols\MyApplication.exe\5AB2A76A278000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/MyApplication.exe/5AB2A76A278000/MyApplication.exe
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/MyApplication.exe/5AB2A76A278000/MyApplication.ex_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/MyApplication.exe/5AB2A76A278000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\MyApplication.exe - file not found
DBGHELP: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe - OK
DBGHELP: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe found
DBGENG:  Partial symbol load found image e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe.
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1B
         e:\MyApplication
         MyApplication.pdb
         AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81\MyApplication.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81\MyApplication.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\MyApplication\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80070003
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1C
         e:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         MyApplication.pdb
         AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\symbols\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81\MyApplication.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\symbols\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81\MyApplication.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: e:\symbols\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/MyApplication.pdb/AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81/MyApplication.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/MyApplication.pdb/AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81/MyApplication.pd_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/MyApplication.pdb/AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81/file.ptr

SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: MyApplication.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: D:\Services\TEST_SET\BuildAgent\work\5862d9870f4438d8\source\MyApplication\obj\Release\MyApplication.pdb - file not found
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MyApplication.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MyApplication.exe
```

The E:\MyApplication directory does contain the MyApplication.pdb file.

Then running the analysis is useless due to the method names from our application being unknown, for example if I try to inspect the crashing exception:

```
0:000> !PrintException /d 00000223b92c1f28
Exception object: 00000223b92c1f28
Exception type:   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Message:          External component has thrown an exception.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000BEE7BFD900 0000000000000000 MyApplication.Wpf.UserControls.dll!Unknown+0x1
    000000BEE7BFD9B0 00007FF8AD7EAF10 System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()+0x70
    000000BEE7BFDA00 00007FF8549A7CF2 MyApplication.Util.Wpf.dll!Unknown+0x82
    000000BEE7BFDA60 00007FF856EF9B02 MyApplication.Wpf.UserControls.dll!Unknown+0xc2
```

What am I missing to make the symbols load correctly?

Comment: You're talking a lot about `MyApplication.pdb`but what about  `MyApplication.Wpf.UserControls.pdb` and `MyApplication.Util.Wpf.pdb`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sorry, yes, those are also in the same folder ```E:\MyApplication```. We are missing 3rd party pdb files but the rest are present where it is our application code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the `!sym noisy` logs where WinDbg is looking; if all else fails, you can just put the pdb exactly where its searching.  For example, create this path:

```
e:\symbols\MyApplication.pdb\AC8AC5D12F6C47259920050B2F46CEF81
```

and then copy MyApplication.pdb into the folder.

A proper approach, though, would probably be to learn about [symstore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681417(v=vs.85).aspx) and use it to build up your local symbol server.